# Rails On Create - all models/controllers - Do Something

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a method to do something in the Application Controller when any new record is created in all models/controllers of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this if you want a method before all controllers :

```rb
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :my_method

  protected

  def my_method
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

Note that you have all these available : https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html

Comment: And you can do `before_action :my_method, only: :create` if you want it to run only on the `create` method. And you can add `skip_before_action: :my_method` to any controllers you want *not* to run the action.

Comment: @JohnP although the catch is the method would run even if the create is unsuccessful...

Comment: That's the nature of a `before_action`. If you want something to happen depending on what happens, you have to do it in the method itself.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks. Actually was a bit obvious, but somehow didn't think of that. Its working, but is there a way to get the ID of the new created record? params[:id] doesn't work.

And to avoid the method to run if unsuccessful, I just used after_action instead of before_action.

Comment: That's a separate question, really: you should be able to use `params[:id]` to get the record within your `after_action` but there probably isn't space in the comments to get into that.

Comment: params[:id] seems like something extracted from the URL, which isn't present on create, only in the show action which only happens next.